# In C# , How can i create a System.Drawing.Color object using a hex value?

Tags: c#, .net, colors, system.drawing.color

In C# , How can i create a System.Drawing.Color object using a value like this #FFFFF,#FGFG01 etc...

Comment: Be aware if you are getting the hex value from the querystring, the hash will be URL encoded as %23.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
string hexValue = "#000000"; // You do need the hash
Color colour = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexValue); // Yippee
```

**Edit:** You do actually need the hash, or the alpha value won't be taken into account. Woops!

Comment: A good answer + bonus points for "Yippee"

Comment: Had to change my if (color == Black) comparison as they're two different objects, so the condition would never have been true. Kept the yippee comment in - just for you!

Comment: Yes. HASH is needed. Otherwise it will throw an error

Answer (score 3):

var my col = Color.FromArgb(int x);

note you need to specify an alpha value as well (probably you want FF for this, i.e. fully opaque, so add 0xFF000000 to the colour hex value)

Comment: +1 He can use Int32.Parse to turn a hex string into an int, just drop the #.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the values to start with FF? E.g. FFFFFFFF = white. This is to add the alpha value to the beginning.

If so, just parse the value with `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb`. It takes an `int` where the first 8 bits are the alpha value. 255 is opaque.

To convert your string into an int, use Int32.Parse. E.g.

```
String HexColourValue = "FABFAB";
System.Drawing.Color colour = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(Int32.Parse("FF"+HexColourValue,
                              System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Make sure that `HexColourValue` doesn't have '#' in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32( str.Substring(1), 16 ));
```

Comment: won't this give an aplha value of 0 which is transparent?

Comment: Yes, it does, if alpha is supported. You would have to use #FF123456 if you want nontransparent colors or add 0xff000000 to the conversion result.